# pass user input to title of graph

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot a simple bar graph in plotly dash

```
team=input()

fig=px.bar(df,x="win_count",y="venue",color="venue",title="Win count at each stadium for :team ")

fig.show()
```

If the user input is: **Brazil**, the title of the graph now is:
*Win count at each stadium for :team*

I want the title to be:
*Win count at each stadium for :Brazil*

How can I pass the user input inside title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has rather simple solution, you can build your title easily:

```
team=input()
title = "Win count at each stadium for :"+team
fig=px.bar(df,x="win_count",y="venue",color="venue",title=title)
fig.show()
```

This should work similarly:

```
team=input()
fig=px.bar(df,x="win_count",y="venue",color="venue",title="Win count at each stadium for :"+team)
fig.show()
```